# How to implement clip-path when working with Sass and CSS modules

Tags: reactjs, sass, jsx, css-modules

The `<svg>` mentioned below the `<img>` must clip the image but the code doesn’t seem to be working. This is a Vite React project.

1. In my opinion, a probable reason could be that I am using CSS modules coupled with Sass and the `id` passed to the `clip-path` property isn't being tracked (as per VS Code). If that happens to be the case, I would really appreciate any solutions that can resolve the issue. I have attached a screenshot of the VS code message and the reason why I think this might be the problem in the form of an observation below.
2. I have tried using `<defs>` in my SVG instead of `<g>` as mentioned in one of the answers, that doesn’t seem to be working as well.
3. I have also tried placing the  element at different locations -- outside  and  and wrapping a single SVG `<path>` (on separate occasions). None of these changes worked.

Observation: When the  element was wrapped simply around a single `<path>` of the SVG, the rest of the paths **were visible** which makes me think the problem is indeed with the way I am referencing the id but I could be wrong.

Also, *I am aware that an alternative would be to use mask instead of clip but I still need it to be clip since I wish to add animations to my component and clip would provide more control over certain properties when transitioning as compared to mask.*

Following is the JSX:

```
import styles from "./FeaturedProjects.module.scss";

function FeaturedProjects() {
  return (
  <section className={styles.secondaryFeaturedProjectsSection}>
         <img
          id={styles.clip_container}
          src={bgImg}
          alt="Processor chipset image."
        />
        <svg
        className={styles.svg}
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          version="1.0"
          width="1280.000000pt"
          height="673.000000pt"
          viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 673.000000"
          preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
        >
          <g
            transform="translate(0.000000,673.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
            fill="#fff"
            stroke="none"
          >
            <clipPath id={styles.myClip}>
              <path d="M1060 5660 l0 -970 975 0 975 0 0 970 0 970 -975 0 -975 0 0 -970z" />
              <path d="M11750 5035 l0 -485 -485 0 -485 0 0 -975 0 -975 483 2 482 3 3 488 2 487 485 0 485 0 0 970 0 970 -485 0 -485 0 0 -485z" />
              <path d="M5910 4135 l0 -485 -485 0 -485 0 0 -485 0 -485 485 0 485 0 0 -490 0 -490 485 0 485 0 0 1460 0 1460 -485 0 -485 0 0 -485z" />
              <path d="M70 2095 l0 -1945 486 -2 c318 -2 488 0 490 7 2 6 3 881 2 1945 l-3 1935 -487 3 -488 2 0 -1945z" />
              <path d="M2990 1120 l0 -970 1460 0 1460 0 0 485 0 485 -975 0 -975 0 0 485 0 485 -485 0 -485 0 0 -970z" />
              <path d="M7860 1605 l0 -485 -487 -2 -488 -3 -3 -483 -2 -482 975 0 975 0 0 485 0 485 485 0 485 0 0 -485 0 -485 1460 0 1460 0 0 970 0 970 -485 0 -485 0 0 -485 0 -485 -975 0 -975 0 0 485 0 485 -970 0 -970 0 0 -485z" />
            </clipPath>
          </g>
        </svg>
   </section>
 );
}

export default FeaturedProjects;
```

SCSS (used along with CSS modules):

```
    .secondaryFeaturedProjectsSection {
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;  
    }  

    .svg{
      position: absolute;
      width: 600px;
      height: 550px;
      margin-left: 10%;
    }
    
    .clip_container {
      // z-index: 100;
      position: relative;
      margin-left: 10%;
      width: 600px;
      height: 550px;
      clip-path: url(#myClip);
      -webkit-clip-path: url(#myClip);
    }
```

[image: #myClip id that is supposed to point at the clipPath]

Thanks for your time!